# Duplicated one-to-many relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities user and notification as following

```
public class Notification
{
    public virtual int? FromUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ToUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUser FromUser { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUser ToUser { get; set; }
}

public class SystemUser 
{
    public virtual ICollection<Notification> SentNotifications { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Notification> RecievedNotifications { get; set; }
}
```

How to make Entity Framework to load notifications in `SentNotifications` list which is `FromUser` is the current user and load notifications in `ReceivedNotifications` list which is `ToUser` is the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `InverseProperty` Data annotation. You can place the annotations on either end of the relationship (or both ends if you want).

```
public class Notification
{
    public int? FromUserId { get; set; }
    public int? ToUserId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SentNotifications")]
    public virtual SystemUser FromUser { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("RecievedNotifications")]
    public virtual SystemUser ToUser { get; set; }
}
```

The second way is using Fluent Api to configure your relationships explicitly. You could, for example, override `OnModelCreating` method of your context and add this code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
  .HasOptional(l => l.FromUser )
  .WithMany(p => p.SentNotifications)
  .HasForeignKey(l=>l.FromUserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
  .HasOptional(l => l.ToUser )
  .WithMany(p => p.RecievedNotifications)
  .HasForeignKey(l=>l.ToUserId);;
```